# VS code and Android Studio can't find emulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Android studio and VS code show me both no devices but flutter doctor shows no issues and the `flutter run` command runs the app fine

Output in Terminal:

```
flutter doctor -v                                      
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.3.8, on Linux, locale de_DE.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.3.8 at /home/nuggetz/Programme/flutter
    • Framework revision e5b1ed7a7f (vor 3 Wochen), 2019-03-06 14:23:37 -0800
    • Engine revision f4951df193
    • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.0.0 571ea80e11)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/nuggetz/Programme/android/
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/nuggetz/Programme/android/
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

EDIT: when i run in Android Studio Tools > Flutter > flutter doctor I get this output:

```
/home/nuggetz/Programme/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.3.8, on Linux, locale de_DE.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.3.8 at /home/nuggetz/Programme/flutter
    • Framework revision e5b1ed7a7f (vor 4 Wochen), 2019-03-06 14:23:37 -0800
    • Engine revision f4951df193
    • Dart version 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.0.0 571ea80e11)

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.


[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should file a bug on Github.

Answer (score 0):

If the status bar reads No Devices Flutter has not been able to discover any connected iOS or Android devices or simulators. You need to connect a device, or start a simulator, to proceed.

The Flutter extension automatically selects the last device connected. However, if you have multiple devices/simulators connected, click device in the status bar to see a pick-list at the top of the screen. Select the device you want to use for running or debugging.

[Flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code)

Comment: you can see in the terminal output that a device is connectet

Answer (score 0):

just move all sdks from /home/nuggetz/Programme/android/ to /usr/lib/android-sdk